# why get I segmentation fault (core dumped) on compiling my code C (linux)

Tags: c, linux, sdl

Here is my code.
Can anyone help me?

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 


int blit_image(char chemin[15],SDL_Surface *fenetre,int posx,int posy) {
    SDL_Surface *temp;
    SDL_Surface *image; 
    SDL_Rect position;

    temp = SDL_LoadBMP(chemin);

    image= SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
    position.x = posx;
    position.y = posy; 
    position.w = image->w; 
    position.h = image->h;

    SDL_BlitSurface(image,NULL,fenetre,&position); SDL_Flip(fenetre);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp); 
    SDL_FreeSurface(image); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    SDL_Surface *fenetre; 
    SDL_Event event; int done=1; SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    fenetre = SDL_SetVideoMode(910,600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    blit_image("resources/images/fondblanc.bmp",fenetre,0,0); 
    blit_image("resources/images/chat.bmp",fenetre,0,0);//cat 
    blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbt.bmp",fenetre,820,25);//dog
    blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbt.bmp",fenetre,820,140); //horse
    blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbt.bmp",fenetre,820,255); //tiger
    blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebt.bmp",fenetre,820,370);//hen
    blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebt.bmp",fenetre,820,485);
    while (done) {

        SDL_WaitEvent(&event); 
        switch(event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT: 
            {
                done=0;
                break; 
            }
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                if ((event.button.x>820)&&(event.button.x<890)&&(event.button.y<115)&&                                                     (event.button.y>25)) 
                { 
                    blit_image("resources/images/chat.bmp",fenetre,0,0); 
                }
                if ((event.button.x>820)&&(event.button.x<890)&&(event.button.y<230)&&         (event.button.y>140))
                { 
                    blit_image("resources/images/chien.bmp",fenetre,0,0); 
                } 
                if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<345)&&(event.motion.y>255))
                { 
                    blit_image("resources/images/cheval.bmp",fenetre,0,0);
                }
                if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<460)&&         (event.motion.y>370))
                {
                    blit_image("resources/images/tigre.bmp",fenetre,0,0); 
                }
                if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<575)&&(event.motion.y>485))
                {
                    blit_image("resources/images/poule.bmp",fenetre,0,0);
                } 
            }

        }

        if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<115)&&         (event.motion.y>25)) 
        {
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbtClic.bmp",fenetre,820,25);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbt.bmp",fenetre,820,140); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbt.bmp",fenetre,820,255); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebt.bmp",fenetre,820,370);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebt.bmp",fenetre,820,485);
        }
        if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<230)&&(event.motion.y>140))
        {
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbtClic.bmp",fenetre,820,140); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbt.bmp",fenetre,820,25);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbt.bmp",fenetre,820,255);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebt.bmp",fenetre,820,370);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebt.bmp",fenetre,820,485);

        }
        if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<345)&&         (event.motion.y>255)) 
        {
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbtClic.bmp",fenetre,820,255);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbt.bmp",fenetre,820,25); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbt.bmp",fenetre,820,140); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebt.bmp",fenetre,820,370); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebt.bmp",fenetre,820,485);

        }

        if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<460)&&(event.motion.y>370)) { 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebtClic.bmp",fenetre,820,370);

            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbt.bmp",fenetre,820,25);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbt.bmp",fenetre,820,140);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbt.bmp",fenetre,820,255);

            blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebt.bmp",fenetre,820,485);
        } 
        if ((event.motion.x>820)&&(event.motion.x<890)&&(event.motion.y<575)&&(event.motion.y>485)) 
        {
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/poulebtClic.bmp",fenetre,820,485);

            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chatbt.bmp",fenetre,820,25);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chienbt.bmp",fenetre,820,140); 
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/chevalbt.bmp",fenetre,820,255);
            blit_image("resources/bouttons/tigrebt.bmp",fenetre,820,370);

        }
    } 

    SDL_Quit(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

i compiled it by using `gcc game.c -o prog -lSDL -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf`

The code compile succeffully but on typing `./prog` to execute the code it display me `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`

Yet the files used exists in the directory

Comment: Run the program in a debugger like gdb and see where it crashes

Comment: *"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"* is NOT a compiler error (unless you found a compiler bug, which is rather unlikely).  Rather, it is more likely you got a *run time* error.   Describe your EXACT steps.  Did you compile the code? Did you link the code? Did you run the code?  Where exactly did you get the error, and how have you tried to debug it?

Comment: i compiled it by using gcc game.c -o prog -lSDL -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf

Comment: @sanaEsprit: **And what was the result of compiling?*** did you get an error? or was the compile successful?  What did you do next? (you must provide information, or we cannot help)

Comment: ***VTC:*** *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need."*

Comment: @abelenky yes the code compile succeffully  but on typing ./prog to execute the code it  display me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: First thing would be to compile with `gcc -o prog -lthis -lthat -Wall` to catch all the compiler warnings.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of `SDL_LoadBMP()` before trying to use it in `SDL_BlitSurface()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you declared the function:

```
int blit_image(char chemin[15],SDL_Surface *fenetre,int posx,int posy) {
```

So that that parameter #1 has 15 characters.

But when you call it, you call it with:

```
 blit_image("resources/images/fondblanc.bmp",fenetre,0,0);
```

That filename is 31-characters by my counting, and will not fit into 15 characters.

I also added some printf-statements to your code which will help you figure out where it crashes.
You should continue to add more printf-statements until you narrow down the crash.

Comment: No printf-debugging. Use real tools like gdb and valgrind.

Comment: I replaced 15 by 50 and I recompiled the code now it displaying me
temp is NULL
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
so the problem must be in the url ?:(

Comment: If `SDL_LoadBMP(chemin);` is returning NULL, you should read the documentation, and check the path carefully, and ***investigate***.

Answer (score 0):

One of ***many*** problems in your code is:

```
int blit_image(char chemin[15],SDL_Surface *fenetre,int posx,int posy)
{
    [...]
}
```

That function is declared to return an `int`.

Do you see a `return` statement in that function?
How does it return an `int` without a return statement?

Your `main` function is declared to return an int, and amazingly, ends with `return 0;`.
How'd you get it right in `main`, and not in your other function?

Comment: While this is definitely an issue that should be addressed, the fact that the return value from `blit_image()` is never captured anyway mitigates that particular oversight, and renders it rather unlikely to be the cause of a segmentation fault...